# Converting MVC2 aspx project to use MVC3 Razor view engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need advice.

We have a MVC2 aspx project that we would want to (nice to do, not need to do) upgrade so that we can use the Razor view engine instead of the aspx/webforms engine.

In total there is about 200aspx files that would need to be converted.

What`s your opinion of how much time it would take? And is it worth doing it?

Answer (score 2):

If you do this manually, it takes long time to do this. But you can use [MVC 3 Project Upgrade Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx) - this will be a good choice

Comment: Upgrading from mvc2 to mvc3 would be the easy part. I`m more concerned about converting all the views into razor

Answer (score 1):

Telerik has [conversion tool](https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter). It works quite well on simple cases, just does not help with converting master pages to layouts. I've used it to convert my project (several hundred views, up to ten master pages) - it took some time to figure out how to map master pages to layouts, but overall went quite well.
Is it worth it?
Well, it depends, mostly on how much is your project covered with tests. Razor syntax is much cleaner, I like layouts better than master pages. I always think, that migrating to new version has one serious advantage - it is a reason to review all your code, refactor things and so on, another serious advantage is to work with current technologies.